# VF tag apex:enhancedList not working in Lightning Experience in Chrome Browser

Tags: visualforce, lightning, chrome

I have a visualforce page that uses **apex:enhancedList** tag.

The page is working absolutely fine in classic experience when I am using Chrome Browser but is not working when I am using Lightning Experience.
When I click Next, Previous links (Pagination) it doesn't respond.

Error in Console: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL ...[image]

Is there any work around ? I tried apex:listView but it didn't serve by necessity as apex:listView doesn't support Type="Activity".

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: What is the API version of the page, try updating it to the recent or bit lower.

Comment: @Raul: The current API version of the page is 45.0. However, I tried setting it to 46.0, 47.0 and even 39.0 but none resolved the issue.